# AWK command for parsing

Tags: awk

I have to parse the table which I am getting from running the command:

```
tshark -q -r  dump.pcap -Y http -z http,tree
```

The table looks like this:

```
=======================================================================================================================================

HTTP/Packet Counter:
Topic / Item            Count         Average       Min val       Max val       Rate (ms)     Percent       Burst rate    Burst start  
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total HTTP Packets      70                                                      0.0120        100%          0.0500        1.641        
 HTTP Request Packets   51                                                      0.0087        72.86%        0.0400        1.494        
  SEARCH                22                                                      0.0038        43.14%        0.0400        1.641        
  NOTIFY                22                                                      0.0038        43.14%        0.0200        1.104        
  GET                   5                                                       0.0009        9.80%         0.0100        1.109        
  POST                  2                                                       0.0003        3.92%         0.0100        3.577        
 HTTP Response Packets  19                                                      0.0032        27.14%        0.0300        4.908        
  2xx: Success          19                                                      0.0032        100.00%       0.0300        4.908        
   200 OK               19                                                      0.0032        100.00%       0.0300        4.908        
  ???: broken           0                                                       0.0000        0.00%         -             -            
  5xx: Server Error     0                                                       0.0000        0.00%         -             -            
  4xx: Client Error     0                                                       0.0000        0.00%         -             -            
  3xx: Redirection      0                                                       0.0000        0.00%         -             -            
  1xx: Informational    0                                                       0.0000        0.00%         -             -            
 Other HTTP Packets     0                                                       0.0000        0.00%         -             -            

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I just want the count column of few lines like Http Request Packets, Search, Notify, Http Response packets. By using command like

```
tshark -q -r  dump.pcap -Y http -z http,tree | awk '/SEARCH/ {print $2}'
```

I am getting the desired output. I want to know if there is a way with which we can do this by running it in a single command.

Comment: Please add your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: output for search is 22. for notify I want 22. For Http request packets I want 51 etc

Comment: Simply post sample Input_file with expected output file in code tags in your post.

Comment: I have already posted the table in the question. Also I have mentioned that I want the "count" column from the table for the rows having "Http Request Packets, Search, Notify, Http Response packets".

Comment: @mg9893, please post the sample output of command `tshark -q -r  dump.pcap -Y http -z http,tree` and expected sample output in your post.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 "tshark table" in the question is an image, clicking on it will give you the sample output of command tshark -q -r dump.pcap -Y http -z http,tree

Comment: @mg9893, please post the output of it in text not in image, so that we could test the command's output too.

Comment: ". I want to know if there is a way with which we can do this by running it in a single command." Do you mean define a shell function so you can say `getIt notify` and it will return `22` ?

Answer (score 2):

If you know field widths you can use `substr()`, and if you are on GNU awk you can set **FIELDWIDTHS**

```
tshark -q -r  dump.pcap -Y http -z http,tree | awk '/HTTP Request Packets|SEARCH|NOTIFY|HTTP Response Packets/{
      print substr($0,1,24), substr($0,25,24)
    }'
```

Would O/P :

```
$  your_command | awk '/HTTP Request Packets|SEARCH|NOTIFY|HTTP Response Packets/{print substr($0,1,24), substr($0,25,24)}'
 HTTP Request Packets    51                      
  SEARCH                 22                      
  NOTIFY                 22                      
 HTTP Response Packets   19
```

Comment: Is there a way with which we can do if we shuffle the order? I mean to say if we input /HTTP Request Packets|HTTP Response Packets|SEARCH|NOTIFY/,  I want output to be 51 19 22 22 instead of 51 22 22 19. Because in my case I am not getting the same order in the table for all the pcaps, so using this command will give me wrong values

Comment: like this : `your_command | awk '/regex1/{var1= substr($0,1,24) OFS substr($0,25,24) }/regex2/{var2= substr($0,1,24) OFS substr($0,25,24) }/regex_last/{print var1 RS var2 RS substr($0,1,24) OFS substr($0,25,24) }'`

Answer (score 0):

This is the best I could come up with (**uses gnu awk**):

```
yourcommand | gawk '
BEGIN {
    FIELDWIDTHS = "24 14"
}
/HTTP R|NOTIFY|GET|POST|SEARCH/ {
    gsub(" +$","",$2)
    print $2
}'
```

If you don't have gnu awk:

```
yourcommand | \
egrep 'HTTP R|NOTIFY|GET|POST|SEARCH' | \
cut -c 25-38 | \
awk '{ gsub("^ +",""); gsub(" +$",""); print }'
```

*Bonus:* this will output with row headers in csv:

```
yourcommand | gawk '
BEGIN {
    FIELDWIDTHS = "24 14"
}
/HTTP R|NOTIFY|GET|POST|SEARCH/ {
    gsub("^ +","",$1)
    gsub(" +$","",$1)
    gsub(" +$","",$2)
    print $1 "," $2
}'
```